# Get proper elements of a selected item

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am currently working on a product management system with spring boot and thymeleaf. I Have a product (id, description, id_process(fk)) and process (id, type, time). Which means a @ManyToOne relation. I created a vue with thymeleaf where I add a new product and choose the process that he got. I would like to automatically recuperate the item (time) of the selected process in his proper field without refilling the field another time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything, can you share us a sample code where it's not working for you?

Comment: <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="material">Material</label>
                    <select name="material.type" id="material">
                        <option th:each="material : ${materials}" th:value="${material}" th:text="${material.type}"></option>
                    </select>
                </div>

Comment: <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="materialPrice">Price of the material</label>
                    <input id="materiaulPrice" class="form-control" type="text" name="materialPrice" th:value="${product.material.materialPrice}">
                    <span class="text-danger" th:errors="${piece.material.materialPrice}"></span>
                </div>

Comment: For example, I want the materialPrice to be recuperated automatically after selecting the appropriate material without filling the field another time, in other terms is to recuperate the data of the selected item in listBox from the database  and be put  in their proper fields